# Multiple Line Commenting Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This question has been asked multiple time, but all the answer are different...

In Visual Studio Window, commenting the selection is

`ctrl` + `k` + `c`

this makes the following

```
this
is
my
code
```

become

```
// this
// is
// my
// code
```

Now, I can't find a solution to make this

```
/*
*  this
*  is
*  my
*  code
*/
```

Do you know how to do it? }
I already tried the `shift` + `alt` + `a`

Comment: VS Version could have influence on possible answers. Which one is in use?

Comment: I don't think there is the built-in. Shift+alt+a is for Visual Studio Code.